# How to map correctly interfaces in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a user interface that has an image property. How do I map it correctly?

**Authenticate**

```
export interface Authenticate {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}
```

**User**

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  image: -- How to map to the image interface below?
}
```

**Image**

```
export interface Image{
  alt: string,
  org: string,
  webImg: string,
  thumbnail: string,
  description: string,
  keywords: any
}
```

Comment: I mostly see them as serialized strings but there may be BLOBs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use other interfaces as types in interface declarations.  So, for example, your User interface could look like:

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  image: Image
}
```